# CSS mover Canvas

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, canvas

Al mover el  hacia cualquier lado, el canvas deja de funcionar, me gustaría saber como moverlo de forma correcta hacia el margen derecho de la pantalla

HTML

```
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>plantillapaint</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="satur">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="combinandoto.css">
    <script src="combinandoto.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="paint">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas" onmousemove="pintar(event);" onmousedown="activar();" onmouseup="desactivar();"></canvas></td>
                <td class="herramientas">
                    <a href="#" onclick="lapiz();"><img src="Fotos/lapiz.png" width="50" height="auto" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="borrador();"><img src="Fotos/goma.png" width="50" height="auto"/></a> <br>
                    <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" onclick="stamano(3);"></div><br />
                    <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" onclick="stamano(5);"></div><br />
                    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" onclick="stamano(10);"></div><br />
                    <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" onclick="stamano(20);"></div><br />
                    <input type="color" id="colores" onchange="scolor();"/>
                    <a href="#" download="canvas.png" id="guardarimagen" >Guardar como imagen</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("guardarimagen").addEventListener("click", guardari, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#paint {
   margin-left: 500px;
  }

#canvas {
    border : solid 1px;
    cursor : url('imagenes_del_rancio/lapizcursor.gif'), default;

}
.herramientas {
    width: 100px;
}
.herramientas div {
    background-color: black;
}
.herramientas div:hover{
    border: solid red 1px;
}
.herramientas img:hover{
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var color = "#000000";
var tamaño = 10;
var pintura = false;

function pintar(event){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var cuadro = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = event.clientX-15;
    var y = event.clientY+35;

    if(pintura){
        cuadro.fillStyle = color;
        cuadro.fillRect(x, y, tamaño, tamaño);
    }
}

function activar(){
    pintura = true;
}

function desactivar(){
    pintura = false;
}

function borrador(){

    document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "url('imagenes_del_rancio/borradorcursor.png'), crosshair";
    color="#FFFFFF";
    document.getElementById("colores").setAttribute("disabled", "");
}

function lapiz(){
    document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "url('imagenes_del_rancio/lapizcursor.gif'), crosshair";
    color = document.getElementById("colores").value;
    document.getElementById("colores").removeAttribute("disabled");
}

function scolor(){
    color = document.getElementById("colores").value;
}
function stamano (numero)
{
    tamaño = numero;
}
function guardari()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imagen = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
this.href = imagen;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el html no salio, lo adjunto por aca         <div id="paint">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas" onmousemove="pintar(event);" onmousedown="activar();" onmouseup="desactivar();"></canvas></td>

Comment: No entiendo cual es el probema. Solo quieres mover el canvas y que el cuadrado quede contra el lado derecho?

Comment: claro, cuando muevo el div que contiene el canvas al lado derecho, el canvas dejar de funcionar

Comment: Y que problemas te muestra, nos cuestra ayudarte con tan poca info. Trata de tomarte tu tiempo y agregar toda la info a la pregunta.

Comment: el problema es que al mover el <div> donde se encuentra el canvas, el cuadro de dibujo deja de funcionar. Internamente el canvas se debe estar quedando en su posición inicial  y solo se mueve el cuadro, por lo que están quedando desfasados.  quiero unirlos

Comment: No podemos saberlo, nos falta info. Segun nos muestras, hay un canvas a la derecha que al pasar el mouse por arriba, intenta ejecutar una función `pintar()` q no existe. Puedes compartirnos el resto?

Comment: manuco, ya compartí el documento entero, gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: gracias por la explicación y paciencia, soy nuevo en la pagina y no la cacho del todo. por querer resumirles el codigo donde pense que estaba utilizando mal alguna propiedad la termine complicando. espero que haya quedado mas claro

Comment: Es entendible. Te recomiendo que leas **[como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)** y asi formutar una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el *clientX* y el *clientY*. Ambos toman el valor de la pantalla y la pos en la que esta el cursor. Es decir que cuando tu canvas esta a la derecha toma la coordenada desfasada. Para eso tiene que restar la propia posición del canvas a tu coordenada x,y:

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

var  x= event.clientX - rect.left;
var  y= event.clientY - rect.top;
```

Luego el resto fue cambiar de lugar el `td` para q el canvas se vea a la derecha.

---

```js
  var color = "#000000";
  var tamaño = 10;
  var pintura = false;
  

        
  function pintar(event) { 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var cuadro = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    var  x= event.clientX - rect.left;
    var  y= event.clientY - rect.top;
    // var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    // var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

    if (pintura) {
      cuadro.fillStyle = color;
      cuadro.fillRect(x, y, tamaño, tamaño);
    }
  }

  function activar() {
    pintura = true;
  }

  function desactivar() {
    pintura = false;
  }

  function borrador() {

    document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "url('imagenes_del_rancio/borradorcursor.png'), crosshair";
    color = "#FFFFFF";
    document.getElementById("colores").setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }

  function lapiz() {
    document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "url('imagenes_del_rancio/lapizcursor.gif'), crosshair";
    color = document.getElementById("colores").value;
    document.getElementById("colores").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }

  function scolor() {
    color = document.getElementById("colores").value;
  }

  function stamano(numero) {
    tamaño = numero;
  }

  function guardari() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var imagen = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    this.href = imagen;
  }
```

```css
  #paint {
    margin - left: 500 px;
  }
  #paint table{
    float:right;
  }
  #canvas {
    border: solid 1px black;
    cursor: url('imagenes_del_rancio/lapizcursor.gif'),
      default;
  }

  .herramientas {
    width: 100 px;
  }

  .herramientas div {
    background - color: black;
  }

  .herramientas div: hover {
    border: solid red 1 px;
  }

  .herramientas img: hover {
    border: solid red 1 px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>plantillapaint</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="satur">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="combinandoto.css">
<script src="combinandoto.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="paint">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="herramientas"> 
          <a href="#" onclick="lapiz();"><img src="Fotos/lapiz.png" width="50" height="auto" /></a>
          <a href="#" onclick="borrador();"><img src="Fotos/goma.png" width="50" height="auto" /></a> <br>
          <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" onclick="stamano(3);"></div><br />
          <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" onclick="stamano(5);"></div><br />
          <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" onclick="stamano(10);"></div><br />
          <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" onclick="stamano(20);"></div><br />
          <input type="color" id="colores" onchange="scolor();" />
          <a href="#" download="canvas.png" id="guardarimagen">Guardar como imagen</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas" onmousemove="pintar(event);" onmousedown="activar();" onmouseup="desactivar();"></canvas>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("guardarimagen").addEventListener("click", guardari, false);
  </script>
</body>
```

Te adjunto una **[respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130415/7291849)** desde la q me base para responderte y que tiene unos ejemplos muy buenos.

---

Comment: muchas gracias bianco, la respuesta fue muy precisa y me diste una muy buena fuente!

Comment: De nada, me alegra poder ayudarte. Cualquier cosa, no dudes en preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

puedes tratar el div como absoluto y moverlo con top,bottom,left, o right 
seria ponerle lo sig a `#paint`

```css
#paint {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

canvas {
  border: solid 1px;
  cursor: url('imagenes_del_rancio/lapizcursor.gif'), default;
}
```

```html
<div id="paint">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"">
                    </canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: sigo sin poder dibujar en el canvas al moverlo

Comment: Entonces tu problema es que no puedes dibujar en el canvas al moverlo?

Comment: efectivamente, ese es el problema

Comment: entonces, explicalo bien por que tu estas redactando otro problema, ese ya es problema con javascript al parecer, deberias mostrar todo el codigo completo